# 'wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003' in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My application crash when I pop to root view controller in click event of UIAlertView.

my code as below :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0 && ([errorCodeNew  isEqualToString:@"IPH_I_LGN_002"])){

     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate =  (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@"3" forKey:@"CurrentSize"];

    NSMutableArray *nsmarrJpName;
    DatabaseLogic *logic = [[DatabaseLogic alloc] init];
    appDelegate.anket_id = [logic getAnketID];

    nsmarrJpName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[logic getDetailScreenItems:[logic getAnketID]] copyItems:YES];

    for (int i = 0;  i < [nsmarrJpName count]; i++) {
        NSString *strKey = [nsmarrJpName objectAtIndex:i];
        [defaults setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:strKey];
        NSLog(@"key : %@", strKey);
    }

    [nsmarrJpName removeAllObjects];
    [nsmarrJpName release];

    appDelegate.strUserFlg = [logic getUserType];

    [logic release]; logic = nil;

    //start download process
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:LOGIN_COMPLETE_NOTIFICATION object:self userInfo:nil];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
}
```

I have tried by replacing `clickedButtonAtIndex` with `didDismissWithButtonIndex` method. But I does not get any result.

Thanks.

Comment: If **popToRootViewControllerAnimated** is the last line of if contition, what happens?

Comment: If popToRootViewControllerAnimated is the last line the crash problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] to the bottom of the function (i.e. after all the other code has run).

Comment: try this but does not get any result.